# How to generate absentee report with date of absent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to generate absentee report. Employees are allocated to specific date range and the daily punching IN/OUT recorded to CheckINOUT table.

**CheckINOUT Table**
EmployeeID-Int
CheckINOUT-smalldatetime

**EmpAllocation Table**
EmployeeID-Int
StartDate-smalldatetime
EndDate-smalldatetime

**Report Format**
EmployeeID | Date Absent

TIA.

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information in this question to enable someone to easily answer without performing a certain amount of guesswork. Assume that you are someone with no knowledge of the problem and read the question again and see if you feel it can be answered without any more information, or get a colleague to read it. If your colleague has questions about what you are trying to achieve, then so will the rest of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this meets your actual requirement but this may be a start for you..Try this(untested).

```
SELECT * 
FROM   empallocation A 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   checkinout B 
                   WHERE  A.employeeid = B.employeeid 
                          AND b.checkinout BETWEEN a.startdate AND b.enddate)
```

I am adding this code based on the link you provided..

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c649/5)

```
CREATE TABLE empalloc 
  ( 
     eid       INT, 
     startdate DATETIME, 
     endate    DATETIME 
  ) 

INSERT INTO empalloc 
VALUES     (001,'2014-10-01','2014-10-15'), 
           (002,'2014-10-10','2014-10-15') 

CREATE TABLE checkinout 
  ( eid     INT, 
    checkin DATETIME ) 

INSERT INTO checkinout 
VALUES     (001,'2014-10-03'),(001,'2014-10-04'),(001,'2014-10-08'),
           (001,'2014-10-09'),(001,'2014-10-10'),(001,'2014-10-11'),
           (001,'2014-10-13'),(001,'2014-10-15'),(002,'2014-10-12'),
           (002,'2014-10-13') 

;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT eid, 
                startdate, 
                endate 
         FROM   empalloc 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT eid, 
                Dateadd(dd, 1, startdate) startdate, 
                endate 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  startdate < endate) SELECT eid, 
       startdate 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  startdate >= '2014-10-01' 
       AND startdate < '2014-10-10' 
EXCEPT 
SELECT eid, 
       checkin 
FROM   checkinout
```

In where condition just add the date range in which u need to generate the report

Comment: Agree with NOT EXISTS but this will not show which date employees absent.

Comment: @r2c3 Startdatedate and endate is present in the empallocation Table. so that indicates which date employees absent

Comment: Thanks for the info but I need to show a report as shown in the below image.

<img src="http://tinypic.com/r/107qhjb/8" width="300" height="300">

Comment: @r2c3 - check now dude

Comment: Seems to miss employee 002...?

Comment: @jim31415 for employee 002 the allocation is from '2014-10-10' to '2014-10-15' so in this range startdate >= '2014-10-01' AND startdate < '2014-10-10' u wont get employee 002

Comment: @Pradeep How do I stop recursion to return rows until current system date if the below condition meet. Was trying like : `WHERE startdate >= @vrDate and stardate < coalesce(@vrDate, GETDATE())` without luck.

Comment: @r2c3 try keeping it here "FROM   cte WHERE  startdate < getdate()"

Answer (score 0):

```
use `LEFT JOIN`

SELECT EA.EmployeeID , EA
FROM EmpAllocation EA
LEFT JOIN CheckINOUT C
on EA.EmployeeId = C.EmployeeID
AND C.CheckINOUT between EA.StartDate and EA.EndDate
WHERE C.checkINOUT is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This will list all absences for each employee.

```
;WITH DateRange AS
(
  SELECT EmployeeID, StartDate, EndDate FROM @EmpAllocation
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  EmployeeID, StartDate + 1, EndDate FROM DateRange WHERE StartDate < EndDate
)


select 
    d.EmployeeID, d.StartDate
from DateRange d
    left join @CheckINOUT c on c.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID and c.CheckInOut = d.StartDate
where c.CheckInOut is null
order by d.EmployeeID, d.StartDate;
```